# How to reference where an image should come from for deployment creation

Tags: docker, kubernetes, digital-ocean

I have an image uploaded in DigitalOcean’s container registry. (Their version of docker HUB)

Via command line, how do I create a Kubernetes deployment using this image?

The full registry name is:

```
http://registry.digitalocean.com/myname/myimage
```

Running following command does not work. Getting image pull failure.

```
kubectl create deployment --image myname/myimage my-app
```

I have already setup the token stuff and set up the config file inside my .kube folder.

Thus the following command does work and my nodes shows up in terminal.

```
kubectl get nodes
```

Issue is with the image.

How do I reference that the docker image should come from the digital ocean registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to login to your private registry, create a secret from those credentials, and mount them in the deployment with `imagePullSecrets`, instructions here:

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/